# Bash command on cURL for Windows

Tags: bash, curl, terminal, hyperledger-fabric

I want to install Hyperledger Fabric to build blockchain apps and the documentation tells me to run a bash command to extract platform-specific binaries.

http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/samples.html#binaries

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/v1.0.5/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s 1.0.5
```

And to this, Terminal outputs:

```
'bash' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

What's the problem I'm facing? I'm running cURL version:
curl 7.58.0 (x86_64-pc-win32) libcurl/7.58.0 OpenSSL/1.1.0g (WinSSL) zlib/1.2.11 WinIDN libssh2/1.8.0 nghttp2/1.30.0

PS: Already installed curl into environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

The command you pasted pipes all its output to a program called `bash`. This is not a standard program for windows.

As stated on the website you've linked:

> If you are running on Windows you will want to make use of the Docker Quickstart Terminal for the upcoming terminal commands. Please visit the Prerequisites if you haven’t previously installed it.

So... use the Quickstart Terminal and read about the Prerequisites first?

Comment: I installed Docker, since the Docker Quickstart Terminal is apparently for old systems. (Tried to run Docker Quickstart Terminal anyway and it tells me it won't run while Hyper-V is active). But the problem above still remains even with Docker activated.